# Rails Gem for twitter follow like functions between users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, twitter-follow

I'm relatively new to the RoR and just finished Michael Hartl's tutorial. And just out of curiosity, are there any gems that makes twitter's follow / unfollow / following / followers function between users of the project more easily integratable? or is the best practice do it from scratch?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple gem solutions out there you might want to take a look at:

**Acts as Follower**

```
https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower
```

**Amistad**

```
https://github.com/raw1z/amistad
```

Whether or not you write from scratch is really a question of how much control you want over the final product. If you or someone you're working with/for wants the ability to change many simple details or one or more concepts, you'll want to write it from scratch. If you're willing to just take what comes to trade off for development speed, gems are a great solution.

Welcome to Rails and StackOverflow!

Comment: These are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!